# Does Azure DataFactory support defining a recursive loop or a loop that modifies it's exit condition?

Tags: loops, recursion, azure-data-factory

Does ADF (v2) allow for recursive activities, or loops which modify the collection they're looping over?

---

***This question is NOT about getting all nested children of a folder, or about finding the min of a collection. Those are just particular examples of where you might use a control structure like this. Don't reply with solutions for the specific cases!***

- Given a folder, you can easily list the direct children of that folder, using the `Get-Metdata` Activity.
- And you can iterate over each of those children.
- And if one of the children is itself a folder, you could get *it's* direct children.

...

But I can't see whether any ADF control-structures would allow you do going down that process until it ends, building a collection of all the files found on the way.
You could build a pipeline that goes an fixed number of levels down, but you can't be *actually* recursive?

Similarly, supposing you wanted to find the smallest element in a set, and you had a `.first()` and a `.filter()` but not a `.sort()` *(Hah! What sort of insane system would do **that**!)*. Then a modifiable loop condition, you could do something along the lines of:

```
While(list.length > 1) {
    list = filter(list, where listElement <= first(list))
}
```

Comment: Can you tell that I've just picked up ADF for the first time :) other beginner questions also recently posted under the same tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to look through a recursive set of files in a N number of directories and then be able to do some filtering based on all the files iterated on?

If so, I would look at setting up a dataset that uses a wildcard for the folder path depending on how you have partitioned out your files.  You should be able to point to something like `2020/*/*/*.csv`.  That's easy enough.  But to filter on what's *IN* the files you would need to use a mapping Data Flow and use that dataset as your source and then build out a pipeline that filters your results.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-filter